# how to see all old commited transactions of a node in geth

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, private-blockchain, testnets

I created a ethereum node using geth and I made certain number of transactions. All the transactions are mined and showing the correct balance.

How can I see all my old transactions?

Also I did transaction by sending the data. It is no where visible to the receiver.

How to see the data sent along with transactions?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're on a private blockchain ?

Comment: yes it is private network

Comment: I don't think that exists yet, sadly. Maybe you can ask devs of etherscan.io and testnet.etherscan.io how they did it :) Maybe the best solution is to do the exact same thing on the tesnet, see what errors and data you have, and try to use that to solve problems on your testnet.